# Failure when deploying Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a container app to Azure and I have hit a roadblock.  I am somewhat new to this space so I hope someone sees something that I am missing.  I am building an image, putting that Image in docker hub, and then deploying the container app in Azure.

Everything is fine in the build step.  The problem starts in the deploy step:

[image]

```
ERROR: (InvalidParameterValueInContainerTemplate) The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Field 'template.containers.album-backend-api.image' is invalid with details: 'Invalid value: "adamcodes716/album-backend-api:10": GET https:: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:adamcodes716/album-backend-api Type:repository]]';.
```

I am assuming that this error is the result of the Azure service connection not being right?    When creating the connection, I ran this command to get the values that I would need:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "spn-aca-azure-pipelines" --role Contributor --scope $RESOURCE_GROUP_ID
```

And this resulted in these values:

[image]

I then took those values and plugged them into an Azure Resource Manager connection:

[image]

I was then able to verify the connection.

I tried both the manual connection and the service principle and got the same error.